# How to remove the dots from a figure produced using plot_date?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure with a solid line, using plot_date.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import show, plot_date
plot_date(time_info, np.arange(3), linestyle='-')
show()
print time_info
```

The print out is

```
[datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 13, 16, 41, 2), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 13, 16, 41, 7), 
 datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 13, 16, 41, 13)]
```

and the produced figure is:

[image]

How to remove the dots?

Comment: You can either use `marker=''` as posted in the answer or `marker='None'`. Both works. Of course the former is less verbose ;)

Comment: Alternatively, you can also just use `'-b'` in your plot command where `b` is for blue color and `-` is for line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `marker=''` or `marker='None'`

```
plot_date(time_info, np.arange(3), linestyle='-', marker='')
```

Or `markersize=0`:

```
plot_date(time_info, np.arange(3), linestyle='-', markersize=0)
```

One more option suggested by @Bazingaa:

```
plot_date(time_info, np.arange(3), '-') # or '-b'
```

Comment: Probably you can also add a third option as I wrote in my comment above. It would be helpful to other people reading your answer in the future.

Comment: Probably one more answer. Just use `'-b'` where `b` is for blue color and `-` is for line. Then there is no need of writing `linestyle` and `marker` or `markersize`.

Comment: Yes, but I though of adding the color for customization sake.